# Visual C++ Cannot find referenced namespace in project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am having problems finding namespace / classes in a referenced project in the same solution.  I've simplified the case to what is shown below

Project1 -- Builds into a Static Lib

Test -- Builds into a dll.

**I added Project1 as a reference in Test**

Project1 Project code:

```
namespace Project1
{
  struct Project1
  {
    Project1() {}
  };
}
```

Test Project code:

```
namespace Test
{
  class Test
  {
  public:
    Test(){}
  private:
    ::Project1::Project1 p;
  };
}
```

Compile Errors:

error C3083: 'Project1': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C2039: 'Project1': is not a member of '`global namespace''

Platform Toolset for both is Visual Studio 2017 (v141)
Windows SDK Version for both is 10.0.17134.0

Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Did you included the headers?

Comment: oh in the linker?

Comment: @Quimby sorry where do I find this?

Comment: ooooooooooh. of course.

Comment: No, I mean to add `#include "path-to-Project1-Code.hpp"` to the second file. Also there should be an Include path in project setings to say to VC where to look for the header files.

Comment: I did not... hence I feel stupid

Comment: Happens to everyone :)